# Building classification

Tags: model, classification, building

## Spot Check Algorithms

I am running code to spot check various classification models and evaluate them but I'm receiving the following warning message: "warnings.warn(some_fits_failed_message, FitFailedWarning)". Can someone help me understand why this warning message is appearing? Below is the code I'm using:

```py
models = []
models.append(('LR', LogisticRegression()))
models.append(('LDA', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis()))
models.append(('KNN', KNeighborsClassifier()))
models.append(('CART', DecisionTreeClassifier()))
models.append(('NB', GaussianNB()))
models.append(('SVM', SVC(kernel = 'rbf')))
models.append(('RF', RandomForestClassifier()))
models.append(('XGB', XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.02, n_estimators=600, objective='binary:logistic', nthread=1)))

# evaluate each model in turn
results = []
names = []
seed = 42
scoring = 'accuracy'
for name, model in models:
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle = True, random_state=seed)
    cv_results = cross_val_score (model, X_train, y_train, cv = kfold, scoring = scoring)
    results.append(cv_results)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f (%f)" % (name, cv_results.mean(), cv_results.std())
    print(msg)
```

Can someone suggest how to resolve this warning message?